# Connect remotely via SSH on docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

I am trying to create an ssh connection to a docker container I built.

I can successfully access the docker container from my remote machine using:
docker exec -it <container_name> /bin/bash

In the docker container, I modified the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config by changing:

Allowroot: yes

Setting a password in my docker container I can create a ssh connection from my remote server by using:

ssh root@localhost -p 2200
(I mapped 2200:22).

This works.

However from my local machine I am trying to connect to the docker container using:

ssh root@192.168.1.33 -p 2200 and I got permission denied.
where 192.168.1.33 is the ip adress of my remote machine where my docker container is running.
Would you have any clue?

thanks :)

ssh root@192.168.1.33 -p 2200 and I got permission denied.
where 192.168.1.33 is the ip adress of my remote machine where my docker container is running.
Would you have any clue?

thanks :)

Comment: Waht's wrong with `docker exec ...`? --- How is the question related to programming? --- Is the container running on the remote server?

Comment: So I am trying to config vs code to code  from inside my container. In order to do so I need to be able connect via ssh.

Comment: Okay. But still: is the container running on the remote server?

Comment: Yes exactly, the container is running in detached mode on the remote server. I can connect to the remote server through port 22. But I got a permission denied while trying to connect to the container through port 2200.

Comment: [This post over at `unix.stackexchange.com`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7700/how-to-enable-remote-login) might be of relevance.

Comment: In my docker container I added my public key to authorized_keys file under ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and it worked. Somehow docker container did not allow me to connect with a password.